# Force use Headset's microphone over AUX

Tags: microphone, headphones, cable, analog, aux-sends

My bluetooth headset has a built-in mic (which works great over bluetooth) but it also comes with a TRS-TRRS cable  (TRS on the headset side) with another mic in it. When connecting the headset with that cable to the PC, the mic quality is VERY low and bad which makes me think the mic in the cable is being used instead of the headset's built-in mic.

My question. What can I do to use the mic built into the headset instead? If I buy a TRRS-TRRS cable (4 poles on both sides, and without a mic in it), would it force to use the headset's built in mic when connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Sound Design.

Does your PC have a combined [TRRS headphone/microphone](https://www.headphonesty.com/2020/09/use-headphone-jack-microphone/) socket? Older PCs may have separate [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_System_Design_Guide#Color-coding_scheme_for_connectors_and_ports) for headphones and microphone.

The fact that your headset was supplied with a cable with a TRS plug suggests that the headset jack (socket) only provides an analog connection to the earpieces not the microphone. You could try a TRRS-TRRS cable but I'd be surprised if it worked.

To use the Bluetooth microphone with a PC you could get a [Bluetooth USB adapter.](https://www.google.com/search?q=usb+bluetooth+adapter+for+pc+for+headphones+microphone) Make sure you get one that is specified to work with stereo headphones and a microphone, not one that just works with e.g. a keyboard. More specifically you can check the headset and adapter share common [Bluetooth profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles). Devices using the [aptX profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AptX) should give better audio quality but this isn't supported by all devices. Windows may not let you tell if [aptX is in use](https://www.howtogeek.com/354321/why-bluetooth-headsets-are-terrible-on-windows-pcs/)

Bluetooth versions prior to 5.0 can't provide high quality stereo output at the same time as microphone input over bluetooth (see the previous link). Bluetooth 5.0 devices should overcome this. Alternatively you may be able to use a cable for wired stereo output whilst using bluetooth for microphone input. You'll need to tell your PC which devices to use. For Windows use the sound app in control panel.

It seems that [improvements](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-is-bringing-the-aac-bluetooth-audio-codec-to-windows-10/) to Windows Bluetooth support are currently (2021-04) being tried out in the Dev(elopment) Channel and should, if successful, make their way into production versions of Windows later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great reply. I already have a bluetooth card but wanted to use the headset's built-in microphone wired to reduce latency. Unfortunately this wouldn't be possible.